# L2TP loadbalancing

Tags: l2tp, lvs

Due to need to scale, I'm setting a new l2tp server using [l2tpns](http://sourceforge.net/projects/l2tpns/) and trying to balance the load between my two l2tp servers using [LVS](http://www.linuxvirtualserver.org/)

LVS configuration

```
ipvsadm -A -u 192.168.10.10:1701 -s sh
ipvsadm -A -u 192.168.10.10:1701 -r 10.10.10.2 -m
ipvsadm -A -u 192.168.10.10:1701 -r 10.10.10.3 -m
```

Each of the l2tp servers is working as standalone but cannot work behind the LVS, so the problem is with the LVS when it passes the traffic to l2tp servers, and I', getting the following error in l2tpns log

```
Out of sequence tunnel 2, (0 is not the expected 1)
Duplicate SCCRQ?
Control message (91 bytes): (unacked 1) l-ns 1 l-nr 1 r-ns 0 r-nr 0
```

Any ideas why does it fail to establish a successful connection with l2tp ?